# How to make llvm jit work in MSVC++

Tags: c++, llvm

It appears that Kaleidoscope example in LLVM has been broken, at least in MSVC++ x64 for a quite while, maybe several months. It doesn't work in MCJIT and in their new Orc JIT framework for a same reason.

```
// Get the address of the JIT'd function in memory.
auto ExprSymbol = J.findUnmangledSymbol("__anon_expr");
```

This expression returns null and cause null pointer error as a result. I can't guess how to make workaround at this moment because call tree is too deep there and may require ~few days of debugging. But in theory, this code is educational and shouldn't cause trouble for newcomers. So maybe i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lang Hames from the llvm mailing list was able to answer this question. It appears that method COFFObjectFile::getSymbolFlags doesn't enable SF_Export flag at all, thus making all created symbols invisible for the Kaleidoscope's findSymbol method in the Windows platform. It is possible to get access to non-exported symbols though, so some kind of workaround is possible.

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way to workaround this was to patch the `findMangledSymbol` function, calling `CompileLayer.findSymbolIn` with `bExportedSymbolsOnly` set to `false`. It doesn't fix the problem but avoids the symptom.

Comment: I did that and filed a tumbleweed bugreport already.

https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25493

Comment: Yes I think it's quite obvious, just wanted to mention. Thanks for providing the link to the bugtracker.