# llvm Kaleidoscope ch 4 - errors with findSymbol

Tags: visual-studio, llvm

When trying input like "3+2" with chapter 4 of Kaleidoscope. The expression returns a null and throws an exception at the following coding. I searched the OS and couple of years ago there was some issue with an earlier version of the example. [How to make llvm jit work in MSVC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600066/how-to-make-llvm-jit-work-in-msvc)
  I use VS 2017 and the Kaleidoscope coding is from LLVM 4.0.

```
auto ExprSymbol = TheJIT->findSymbol("__anon_expr");
assert(ExprSymbol && "Function not found");
```

Comment: What did you modify in the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @AlexDenisov I am trying to build the Kaleidoscope example. In the CMakelists.txt I tried the following: (1)  access llvm-config (2) copied some macros from the source tree so that I can continue to use the macro add_kaleidoscope_chapter (3) linked libraries.

Comment: @AlexDenisov It appears the errors have to do with some include_directories I added for the chapter 4. Why would the include_directories cause any trouble? I thought they could be redundant but harmless.