# LLVM 6.0.0 HowToUseJit example program seg faults

Tags: llvm, jit

I compiled LLVM 6.0.0 on Windows for x64 as a DLL, and tried running the HowToUseJit example program, and it seg faulted. How do you fix it?

Source code for the example:
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/release_60/examples/HowToUseJIT/HowToUseJIT.cpp

This line was causing the seg fault in the example:

```
GenericValue gv = EE->runFunction(FooF, noargs);
```

Comment: Is it similar to this, or there's something new?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600066/how-to-make-llvm-jit-work-in-msvc

Answer (score 0):

I think the HowToUseJit example is incomplete. You need to make the following changes in order to make it work:

Add the following include:

```
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/MCJIT.h"
```

This will call some static initializer function which is required for JITting to work in LLVM.

You also need to add a call to this function inside main before running the JITted function:

```
LLVMInitializeNativeAsmPrinter();
```

This function is required to produce assembly for the target machine.